# Why does my sticky navigation doesn't work on my ipad?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My one-page website (http://www.stefaanoyen.be) features a sticky navigation, but it doesn't work as expected on my iPad. It always stays on top of the page, but when I click the links, nothing happens. The links only work when I'm on the top of the page or when the section the link is pointing to is already partially visible.

I don't know if this is a javascript, css or html problem. In short, I have no clue why it's going wrong, please help me out here : )

Thanks so much for helping me out!
Stefaan

Comment: You can find the html code here: http://pastebin.com/pv9uFc2t --- CSS goes here: http://pastebin.com/LDeF7ztH --- And the sticky navigation javascript goes here: http://pastebin.com/HiS5vtLS

Comment: Super excited to look through all of this code for you! Sike... Try and pin-point the problem, and post that specific code in your question not in a comment

Comment: As I just said, I don't know where to look for the problem. That's why I'm asking the question... Thanks for your helpful feedback though : )

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure `postion:fixed` on mobile browsers is not supported. Check out this quirksmode article, it explains why. http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/12/the_fifth_posit.html

Comment: It is on iOS 5 and up, and has always been on Android. http://caniuse.com/css-fixed

Comment: So position:fixed is not the problem? Do you guys think it's a css problem, so we can narrow it down a bit? Thanks a lot!